# assetic - unable to write assets

Tags: php, assetic

Here's my directory structure (this is just a test project):

```
stan@mypc:/generate_assets$ sudo tree -L 3 -p
.
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  assets
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x]  css
│       ├── [-rw-r--r--]  test1.css
│       └── [-rw-r--r--]  test2.css
├── [-rw-r--r--]  composer.json
├── [-rw-r--r--]  composer.lock
├── [drwxrwxrwx]  public
├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  run
└── [drwxr-xr-x]  vendor
     ....skipping...
```

Here's my simple script ('run' file) that supposed to generate assets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php
    //loading composer's autoload
    chdir(__DIR__);
    if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
        include 'vendor/autoload.php';
    }

    use Assetic\Asset\AssetCollection;
    use Assetic\Factory\AssetFactory;
    use Assetic\Asset\FileAsset;
    use Assetic\Asset\GlobAsset;
    use Assetic\Filter\LessFilter;
    use Assetic\Filter\CssMinFilter;
    use Assetic\AssetWriter;
    use Assetic\AssetManager;

    //Asset manager
    $am = new AssetManager();

    //Add all css files
    $css = new GlobAsset('assets/css/*.css', array(new CssMinFilter()));
    $am->set('basecss', $css);

    // Dumping assets into public
    $writer = new AssetWriter('public');
    $writer->writeManagerAssets($am);
```

So - I expected that css files from assets/css would be combined, minified and dumped into public directory under name 'basecss.css'. Here 's the exception I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to write file public/' in /generate_assets/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/AssetWriter.php:106
Stack trace:
#0 /generate_assets/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/AssetWriter.php(65): Assetic\AssetWriter::write('public/', '*{color:green}?...')
#1 /generate_assets/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/AssetWriter.php(54): Assetic\AssetWriter->writeAsset(Object(Assetic\Asset\GlobAsset))
#2 /generate_assets/run(31): Assetic\AssetWriter->writeManagerAssets(Object(Assetic\AssetManager))
#3 {main}
  thrown in /generate_assets/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/AssetWriter.php on line 106
```

So  - It seems like assetic tries to dump file named as 'public' instead of 'public/basecss.css'?   Any help?

**P.S. RESOLUTION:**

Ok. soo. Apparently I must run

```
$css->setTargetPath('css_file_name.css');
```

And then it worked...

Comment: Please post your complete solution as an answer to your own question to help other people.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted for the benefit of other people looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely clear from the documentation, but it does mention in the [Dumping Assets to static files](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic#dumping-assets-to-static-files) section that

```
$writer->writeManagerAssets($am);
```

"will make use of the assets' target path."  So yes, as you suggested setting the target path before writing the asset will fix the problem:

```
$css->setTargetPath('css_file_name.css');
```